# Setting up unsecure telnet

Tags: command-line, telnet

I want to demonstrate serial communications in a class. Is it possible/how to set up a good old port 23 unencrypted console service in Ubuntu?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt install telnetd` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install and start a telnet server with this small process. For your information, telnet default port is not 22 (ssh) but 23.

```
sudo apt install inetutils-telnetd telnet
```

Edit the file `/etc/inetd.conf` and comment out the following line

```
telnet  stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/telnetd
```

Then restart inet server.

```
sudo systemctl restart inetutils-inetd
```

To snif packages, use then tcpdump. You can install with the following command.

```
sudo apt install tcpdump
```

Use the following command to display the traffic on port 23 (keep the terminal open, and open a new one).

```
sudo tcpdump -A -i lo dst port 23
```

Finally, run telnet on your computer.

```
telnet localhost 23
```

Login with your local account, you will see the written text in clear into tcpdump.

[image: telnet]